# How to iterate over a nested field in another column to create a new column based off another value?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a column in a df that is nested json in a list like so:

```
col1     nested-filed
1        [{nested_data}]
```

the data in the nested filed looks like this:

```
[{'field': 1, 'timestamp': 1511404149332, 'changed-timestamp': 0, 'identities': [{'type': 'leadid', 'value': '123-456', 'timestamp': 1488815181110}, {'type': 'ID', 'value': '0987654321', 'timestamp': 1489691285116}, {'type': 'EMAIL', 'value': '1@1', 'timestamp': 1488815179334, 'is': True}]}]
```

By row I want to pull out `email` and `ID` so the new df looks like this:

```
col1     nested-filed          email           ID
1        [{nested_data}]       1@1.com         0987654321
```

How would I do this? I have millions of rows in the dataframe that I need to pull out those fields for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try out this -

```
import ast
df.nested_filed = df.nested_filed.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))

# Store in a new column named email
df['email'] = df.nested_filed.apply(lambda x: x[2]['value'])

# Store in a new column named ID
df['ID'] = df.nested_filed.apply(lambda x: x[1]['value'])
```

Comment: when I run `df.nested_filed` line i get error `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`. When I change `df['nested_filed']`, i get error `ValueError: malformed node or string:`

Comment: provide the reproducible code, so that I can check from start

Comment: `df['nested-field'] = df['nested-field'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))` this is the line that caused the `ValueError: malformed node or string: `

Comment: @RustyShackleford - It seems not valid json

Comment: @jezrael this is how the API is giving me the data, is there anyway I can convert it to valid json?

Comment: @RustyShackleford - Not easy answering, but first I suggest test [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

Comment: @RustyShackleford if you can get a proper json then there's no need for first line which includes `ast.literal_eval()`. Just proceed with the rest 2.

Comment: @jezrael I used this line to create new df out of the nested json, but I Can not join it back to the df because there are no common fields. 
`new_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(x)) for x in df['nested-field']],ignore_index=False)` from here I have to do the same line again for nested `identities`

Comment: @RustyShackleford - So if use `df = json_normalize(json_data)` not get DataFrame filled by list and dictionaries, so possible use `df['email'] = df.nested_filed.apply(lambda x: x[2]['value'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael when I use `df = json_normalize(json_data)` I get error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`, but if I use `pd.read_json(json_data)` it works but I am at the same point where I have the nested list of dictionary objects. `df['email'] = df.nested_filed.apply(lambda x: x[2]['value'])` gives me error `IndexError: list index out of range`